# "413 Request Entity Too Large" Error on Office 365 Graph API for SendMail using MIME

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api

I was happy to see Microsoft added support to SendMail and using a MIME file.  But, it seems it has the issue most graph APIs had (or have) and that is the 4mb limit.  And because the MIME needs to be base64 encoded, that means we're down to about 2.8MB in actuality.

Error returned when over the limit is:
"413 Request Entity Too Large"

In 2022 that limit is pretty small as most customers are now emailing PDF attachments of POs (a lot of them raster image PDFs, so bigger), invoices, etc.  Just wondering if there is a workaround or if MS is planning on updating this feature as it is a GREAT feature to have (like GMail, et all have).

I have a lot of customers using my software and this feature will make their transition from in house exchange servers or other online email clients to Office 365.